# Fragment shader parameter with attribute 'color' for macOS

Tags: ios, macos, metal

I am trying to port the simple [iOS sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalDeferredLighting/Introduction/Intro.html) to macOS. Metal  compiler says

```
Fragment shader parameter with attribute 'color' is supported only on iOS (requires -std=ios-metal1.[0|1|2]).
```

How to overcome this error? Where can I find a document that points out the Metal API differences between macOS and iOS?

[Here](https://github.com/necktwi/MetalDeferredLighting.git) is the Xcode project with `macOS` target. The above error is thrown by the `Light.metal`.

macOS 10.13
intel i5-5257u Iris 6100

Answer (score 4):

In the future, show which specific file from that sample app is producing the error and the exact line. Or, since you're porting (modifying) the example, show the fragment shader code from your project. Also, indicate which version of macOS you are using.

In theory, [this PDF](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) should show the differences among platforms. It's perhaps not obvious, but I believe that this features falls under "Programmable Blending" in that table. Basically, getting the existing color from the render target(s) is mainly useful to use the original value when computing a new value, i.e. perform a custom blend of new values with the old color.

The [Metal Shading Language spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) does say, in section 4.3.4.4, Attribute Qualifiers for Fragment Function Input:

> The `[[color(m)]]` attribute qualifier is only supported in iOS.

If the shader with the error is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalDeferredLighting/Listings/MetalDeferredLighting_Light_metal.html, then it's really only outputting to the `light` render target (attachment 3). The others it's just preserving (and reading as inputs to its computations). For the `light` texture, it's (effectively) reading from and writing to it.

So, on macOS 10.13+, you may be able to use the texture read-write capability, depending on the pixel format of the light texture and the capabilities of the GPU. You'd do the render pass for this part differently than on iOS. You wouldn't specify any render targets. The fragment shader would return `void`. All of its output would be via texture writing. Rather than using the textures as render targets (color attachments), you'd pass them through the texture table. You wouldn't use the `FragOutput` type with its `[[color(n)]]` fields, you'd receive the textures as input parameters using the `[[texture(n)]]` attribute. You would `read()` (not `sample()`) from the textures at the fragment position (`uint2(in.position)`).

So, something like:

```
fragment void lightFrag(VertexOutput in [[stage_in]],
                        constant LightFragmentInputs *lightData [[buffer(0)]],
                        texture2d<float, access::read> normal [[texture(0)]],
                        depth2d<float, access::read> depth [[texture(1)]],
                        texture2d<float, access::read_write> light_tex [[texture(2), raster_order_group(0)]])
{
    uint2 pos = uint2(in.position);
    float3 n_s = normal.read(pos).rgb;

    float scene_z = depth.read(pos);

    float3 n = n_s * 2.0 - 1.0;

    // Derive the view-space position of the scene fragment in the G-buffer
    // Since the light primitive and the G-buffer were rendered with the same view-projection matrix,
    // we can treat the view-space position of the current light primitive fragment as a ray from the origin,
    // and derive the view-space position of the scene by projecting along the ray with (scene_z / v_view.z).
    // Our scene view-space position is also the view-vector to the scene fragment.
    float3 v = in.v_view * (scene_z / in.v_view.z);

    // Now, we have everything we need to calculate our view-space lighting vectors.
    float3 l = (lightData->view_light_position.xyz - v);
    float n_ls = dot(n, n);
    float v_ls = dot(v, v);
    float l_ls = dot(l, l);
    float3 h = (l * rsqrt(l_ls / v_ls) - v);
    float h_ls = dot(h, h);
    float nl = dot(n, l) * rsqrt(n_ls * l_ls);
    float nh = dot(n, h) * rsqrt(n_ls * h_ls);
    float d_atten = sqrt(l_ls);
    float atten = fmax(1.0 - d_atten / lightData->light_color_radius.w, 0.0);
    float diffuse = fmax(nl, 0.0) * atten;

    float4 light = light_tex.read(pos);
    light.rgb += lightData->light_color_radius.xyz * diffuse;
    light.a += pow(fmax(nh, 0.0), 32.0) * step(0.0, nl) * atten * 1.0001;
    light_tex.write(light, pos);
}
```

If you can't use texture read-write, then you'll probably need to use two textures. You'd pass the old light texture as a read-only parameter and have the fragment shader return a new value (as a `float4` return type) into a new light texture. You'd either use that new light texture for the remainder of the frame's rendering where the original code used the old light texture, or you'd copy the result in the new light texture back to the old one.